# Scala Json - List of Json

Tags: json, scala

I have the below code and the output from my program. However, I could not create a `List` of Json (desired output) given below. What kind changes do I need to do in the existing code?

```
case class Uiresult(AccountNo: String, Name: String)

val json = parse(jsonString)
val elements = (json \\ "_source").children
for (acct <- elements) {
  val m = acct.extract[Source]
  val res = write(Uiresult(m.accountNo, (m.firstName + m.lastName))
  println(res)
}
```

Output from current program:

```
{"AccountNo":"1234","Name":"Augustin John"}
{"AccountNo":"1235","Name":"Juliet Paul"}
{"AccountNo":"1236","Name":"Sebastin Arul"}
```

Desired output:

```
[
{"AccountNo":"1234","Name":"Augustin John"},
{"AccountNo":"1235","Name":"Juliet Paul"},
{"AccountNo":"1236","Name":"Sebastin Arul"}
]
```

Comment: Looks like you need to create some sort of list inside and append `res` to it, then do a final print outside the flatmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a list for the for comprehension, use the `yield` keyword. This will return the values from the iterations and create a list for you, which you then can assign to a `val`.

```
val list = for (acct <- elements) yield {
  val m = acct.extract[Source]
  val res = write(Uiresult(m.accountNo, (m.firstName + m.lastName))
  res
}
```

This can be written even shorter,

```
val list = for (acct <- elements) yield {
  val m = acct.extract[Source]
  write(Uiresult(m.accountNo, (m.firstName + m.lastName))
}
```

The type of list (`Array`, `List`, `Seq`, etc.) will be determined by the type of `elements`. Other data structures such as set dictionaries are also possible to use in this way.

---

To print the output into the exact format as in the "desired output" above, use `mkString`.

```
println(list.mkString("[\n", ",\n", "\n]"))
```